# SQL convert a proprietary numeric date to mmddyy

Tags: sql-server

I have a date column in a SQL Server table that is a 5 digit number, I believe it is based on the number of days since 1/1/1980. I am trying convert it to a `mm/dd/yyyy` date. I also use Crystal Reports and with CR have used this to convert it.

```
Date ({yes01ph.drawer_dt} + 29221)
```

For reference here are some conversion.

```
13920  =  02/10/2018
13921  =  02/11/2018
13922  =  02/12/2018
etc...
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `DATEADD`, e.g.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 13920, '1980-01-01');

10/02/2018 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **`DATEADD()`** to add the number to the date **`1980-01-01`** and then convert it to the required format, **`dd/mm/yyyy`**.

**Query**

```
declare @t as table(
  [num] int
);

insert into @t([num])
select 13920 union all
select 13921 union all
select 13922 union all
select 13923 union all
select 13924;

declare @base as date = '1980-01-01';

select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(day, [num], @base), 101) as [date]
from @t;
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/903619/sql-convert-a-proprietary-numeric-date-to-mmddyy)**